# Table row highlights a picture area

Tags: css, image

I have a table with four rows that highlight on mouse over. I also have a picture with four areas that correspond to the rows in the table. I need the areas in the picture get highlighted as well as the table rows.

This pictures illustrates my problem:
http://projekty.freshynek.cz/table-roll-over-picture-highlight.jpg

[image]

Comment: It would be great if you add a code here. That will help us to make changes in existing code.. We just can help you, not work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to split image and assign different selectors to each image area corresponding to the rows, and add javascript to highlight these areas when hovering the rows.

Another way is to create areas on top of the image, example:

```js
function getArea(elm) {
   var index = /row([0-9])/.exec(elm.id)[1];
   //console.log(index);
   return document.querySelector("#area"+index);
}
function highlight(elm) {
   getArea(elm).classList.remove("hidden");
}
function removehighlight(elm) {
   getArea(elm).classList.add("hidden");
}
```

```css
.row {
  width: 200px;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  color: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.area {
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
#areas {
  position: absolute;
}
#area1 {
  background: #8b5fff;
  height:50px;
  width: 60px;
  left: 40px;
  top: 100px;
}
#area2 {
  background: #FF8080;
  height:20px;
  width: 30px;
  left: 80px;
  top: 10px;
}
#area3 {
  background: #E1E100;
  height:60px;
  width: 40px;
  left: 120px;
  top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="row1" class="row" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseout="removehighlight(this)">row 1</div>
<div id="row2" class="row" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseout="removehighlight(this)">row 2</div>
<div id="row3" class="row" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseout="removehighlight(this)">row 3</div>
<div id="areas">
  <div id="area1" class="area hidden">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="area2" class="area hidden">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="area3" class="area hidden">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
  <img src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/e4ea437b24f9ddf2bcf52604ceae28e4?s=200">
```

Example with multiple tables: http://jsfiddle.net/8mvahL1o/35/

Another complex example: http://jsfiddle.net/urg62cpy/19/

Reverse example: http://jsfiddle.net/urg62cpy/24/ with onclick over `.area`s.

Comment: This is really cool. I reserve the right to steal this and use it in the future.

Comment: @ecg8 Feel free to use it :)

Comment: @BladeMight
Thank you for your help. The divs are rectangular and I need the roll over on image in different shapes. It should look like this preview picture:[https://itmonkey.cz/projekty/hilleho/1st-floor.jpg]
I have tried your code at this page:
(https://itmonkey.cz/projekty/hilleho/nabidka-bytu.html)

Comment: Thank you @BladeMight for your help.
The divs are rectangular and I need the highlighted areas in different shapes - have a look at this picture, please:
https://itmonkey.cz/projekty/hilleho/1st-floor.jpg

The page code:
https://itmonkey.cz/projekty/hilleho/nabidka-bytu.html

I also dont know how the get the divs representing the rows, in to my table.
Thank you

Comment: I have replaced the area div's colour with an image - so the shape is now sorted:
https://itmonkey.cz/projekty/hilleho/nabidka-bytu.html

Now I need to apply the effect to the actual rows in the table, instead being applied to the div.

Comment: @Freshynek Set each `<tr>` in your table, as in my div rows, and you can even discard the classes/id from `<tr>`'s, because you can use `rowIndex` property, example: http://jsfiddle.net/8mvahL1o/28/

Comment: @Freshynek also you can dynamically set the `<tr>`'s onmouse(over/out) using js,  here another example: http://jsfiddle.net/8mvahL1o/30/

Comment: @BladeMight thank you. it is working very well.
If I add <thead> it does not work as I need. Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/8mvahL1o/31/
The last row does not show.

Comment: @BladeMight
First problem: when I add <thead><tr> into the table, it shows different areas.
Second problem: I have 5 images and 5 tables on the HTML page. When mousing over other tables - it still shows areas on the first image.
Thank you for your help.
http://jsfiddle.net/8mvahL1o/32/

Comment: @Freshynek 1st-problem: You should add check for that `tr` in thead. 2nd-problem: It is quite simple if you group the tables, and areas. Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/8mvahL1o/35/

Comment: @BladeMight
Thank you for your help. Works well and I learned something new. Awesome!

Comment: @Freshynek Accept as answer, please.

Comment: Hi @BladeMight
I struggle to repeat the same highlight effect on divs only.
I have a house picture with floors and I need the floors to get highlights on rollover and on press jumt to an anchor. I struggle with the JavaScript, the rest should be O.K. The code is on the same page, as the finished tables with hightlights.
Here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/urg62cpy/10/

Comment: @Freshynek there just different selectors for index of tables and index of your `floor`s, just use their id and take number from it, next about `areas` if thats is the only one `areas` you should remove it, and use `#area{index}` directly at `getArea` function, a bit unfinished http://jsfiddle.net/urg62cpy/13/, sorry I'm busy now...

Comment: @Freshynek Hi, I fixed your script: http://jsfiddle.net/urg62cpy/18/, The problems were: 1. `Wrong links to images` in CSS, e.g. missing `/hilleho/` in path. 2. Image margins positioning, when you try to zoom in/out the page. 3. Added JS to retrieve the id from `floor` divs, or from headers `h3` of these `div`,  also I added dynamic event Installing by CSS selector, see `installHighlightEvents` function. Overall it looks just like you want. 

*P.S.* Please accept as answer if it **does help** you.

Comment: @BladeMight Hi, I am sorry - I need it the other way round. I need to mouse over the floors on the top building image, the floors should highlight and on mouse press, it should jump to the corresponding anchor in the text below.
I want to accept your answer, but I dont know how to do it. You help me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: @Freshynek Easy, just use onclick event of each `.area` and get index from area, find appropriate floor element, and then just scroll to that element see: http://jsfiddle.net/urg62cpy/23/

Comment: @Freshynek Here: [image](https://i.imgur.com/f219Ygq.gif), around my answer will be a checkmark ✓ click on it, and it will become green ✅.

Comment: Thanks again @BladeMight you helped me a lot.

Comment: Hi @BladeMight, I would like 2 more things. 
When I click on the top building, I want to smooth scroll to appropriate section (represented by id="skok+number") Right now it jumps to the id and I need to replace the jump by smooth scroll. Like this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/freshynek/t6kLcupb/13/

When I am on the 5th floor, I can see two flats. I want to click on the flat and open the details URL: "5NP_byt-XVI.html" Right now the clicks on the flats dont work wery well.

You can see the published website here: https://itmonkey.cz/projekty/hilleho/nabidka-bytu.html

Comment: @Freshynek The code `jsfiddle.net/freshynek/t6kLcupb/13` actually just replaces the onclick events of `.link` elements so that they use `jQuery`'s animate and scrollTop, so you should just replace the click events on your site, e.g. `.area`'s, try doing the same as in your code except use the `.area` selector, so that clicking on any `.area` will make it *scroll with animation*. P.S. On your site I've seen that you using `a href` inside a `div` elements(`#area` elements), the `a` is unnecessary here, it is just creates empty HTML parameter, since the element is already `div`.

Comment: @Freshynek Also you should replace my way to scroll inside the `goToFloor` function with `jQuery` animated one.

Comment: @Freshynek Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BladeMight/h4yu0nzk/9/

Comment: @BladeMight I realy struggle with this. I put all your code in my website, and it does not work. Maybe it is the jquery-2.1.4.min.js library. I dont know:
https://itmonkey.cz/projekty/hilleho/nabidka-bytu.html

Comment: @BladeMight Is it possible to open a new html page with the click on the highlighted area?
Illustration here:
https://itmonkey.cz/projekty/hilleho/1st-floor_flat-01_opens-detail.png
The Detail link opens this page: 
https://itmonkey.cz/projekty/hilleho/1NP_byt-I.html

Comment: @Freshynek Console says its undefined, that means its included too late, in body tag, instead include the `jQuery` in `<head>` tag, e.g. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`, for testing try putting this line in your browser console on your website: `var jq = document.createElement('script');jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);jQuery.noConflict();` at https://itmonkey.cz/projekty/hilleho/nabidka-bytu.html

Comment: @Freshynek The same way you used to highlight the parts(areas) when you hover over table's row, you can use reverse of that way for onclick of `areas` index and `area` index to find appropriate table row and click the needed info link.

Comment: Hello @BladeMight, I am not able to make the divs in the picture > open the Details link. I tried but messed it all up. I also would like to add table rows highlight when hovering over the picture.
To summarize it: When I roll over the picture, I want to see table rows highlighted and when I click on a flat, I want to open the Details link. 
Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/freshynek/ot1udrvx/27/

Comment: @Freshynek Yes, that wasn't hard... really. see https://jsfiddle.net/BladeMight/ot1udrvx/46/ i posted there comments inside js functions. see `installClickEvent` and `openTableDetailsByArea` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the $(document) with jQuery(document) and it is working.